# Communicating and Exchanging Data with Bonjour or GameKit?

Tags: p2p, gamekit, bonjour

We are using GameKit to communicate and exchange data in peer-to-peer mode between iOS devices like iPhones and iPads. My understanding is that GameKit is built on top of Bonjour, but I am not familiar with Bonjour. Can we use Bonjour for the same communication/data exchange tasks instead of GameKit? If so, is there an advantage of using Bonjour? Should we stick with GameKit since it offers a high-level API rather than going down that stack? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. The team decided to use node.js and JSON to exchange data and avoid GameKit/Bonjour. We hit a 16 peer limitation with GameKit and going through the Internet offers more advantages.